# WebGL in Node with Fabric.js

Tags: node.js, webgl, fabricjs, server-side

I have a Fabric project which incorporates a custom WebGL filter. The filter works correctly in the browser, but when I run the same code in a Node app and load from a Fabric JSON, the canvas doesn't render if I was attempting to use my WebGL based custom filter.

It appears that in a Node context, Fabric defines WebGL as unsupported - is there possibly a way around this, for me to incorporate something like headless-gl into my Fabric app in order to still be able to render my fragment shader based filter?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

WEBGL is a browser api.
fabric.js on node make use of node-canvas in order to draw on a canvas.
This canvas in node is cairo backed and does not have any hardware acceleration that i know of.

You should probably write the non webgl version of your filter or switch to something like an headless browser and see if in your platform WEBGL is then supported.

Example:

Having a virtual server you probably do not have access to WEBGL from the headless browser, nor from a dedicated server with a video card ( if any ) that does not have the required capabilities or just the required driver for the capabilities.